# dataURL not working when the context of the canvas is an image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i was trying to download the context of the canvas as an image using dataURL() through the  following code but it's not working for some reason. However, when i replace the context of the canvas to be something else besides the image it actually works, so can you tell how can i fix this

```
    <a href="#" id="downloader"  >Download!</a>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

        <script>
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            var image = new Image(60, 45); 
        
            image.onload = function () {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                canvas.width = image.naturalWidth;
                canvas.height = image.naturalHeight;
                ctx.drawImage(image, 0, -60);
            } 
            image.src = 'image.png';

            $('#downloader').click(function(){
                $(this).attr('href', document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream"));
                $(this).attr('download', "Picture.png");   

            });
    </script>
```

Comment: What does the javascript console say? (Ctrl-Shit-I brings up the dev-tools in Chrome - unsure of others) Sounds like you might be using an image but not using a localhost server (page url will start with file:/// if this is the case) It'll be a cross-origin problem if so - the console will tell you what the error is. ;)

Comment: "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported." thats the error i'm getting. however, indeed i'm not running the code on a localhost server, so i'll try to run it and see if that was the problem

Comment: thank you so much, indeed that was the problem. now it works!

Comment: rock'n'roll.. Sounds like you got a new set of toys to play with too. Enjoy the dev-tools. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your JS should be:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var image = new Image(60, 45);

//First add src, then set the height and width
image.src = 'image.png';

image.onload = function() {
  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;
  // Draw image from start and not from behind the axis
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
}

$('#downloader').click(function() {
  $(this).attr('href', document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL("image/png"))
  $(this).attr('download', "Picture.png");

});
```